# Finding a "optimal" delta in a number series equation name?

Tags: c++, math

I have a series of samples in an array which compare a fans Speed to the Temperature of a component, and I want to find the optimal balance where a increase in RPM is no longer efficient enough to be warranted.

I have an array which looks like this:

```
Sample: 0, Speed: 20, Temperature: 33.40
Sample: 1, Speed: 25, Temperature: 32.50
Sample: 2, Speed: 30, Temperature: 31.07
Sample: 3, Speed: 35, Temperature: 30.12
Sample: 4, Speed: 40, Temperature: 27.00
Sample: 5, Speed: 45, Temperature: 26.80
```

Now at some point there is a diminishing return in terms of rate of the fan and temperature drop compared to the noise of the fan, and I cannot figure out what this equation is called. Any help greatly appreciated.

I have tried finding the delta between initial temperatures, and sample temperatures, but choosing the ones with greatest difference is not the way. Since I need to take into account the differences between each sample aswell.

EDIT: Im searching for the name of the equation. So does anyone know this equation?

EDIT2: I was thinking of doing something like weighting the RPM of the motor, and using it as a penalty when selecting the temperature deltas. The RPM of the motor is linear, but the temperatures are not, so I should be able to intersect these somehow.

Comment: You may be wondering why all the down votes - well, you've not used a "?" at all, and you've not said what you've tried, so how can people help?

Comment: So you want the derivative of the temperature with respect to fan speed. You can approximate it by doing (t2-t1)/(s2-s1) at each time step.... probably the easiest way even if it is a rough measure. There will inevitably be noise in your measurements as well which can throw off your algorithm if it just compares things one time step at a time without any filtering.

Comment: Ive clarified, im looking for the name of the equation. Since im sure it exists.

Comment: I have found this, but not sure if it fits. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminishing_returns

Comment: That data looks really noisy! I would have expected (theory-wise), that the differences between temperatures are monotonically-decreasing while keeping the speed-steps constant. It might be wise to interpolate the temperatures / use a model to fit some function to it which is aware of the noise. Then you can of course calculate gradients. But even after the calculation: what does ```optimal balance``` mean? You got no real cost-function here. Inf speed, will have min-temp; while 0-speed will have max-temp. The chosing of a point in between is a model-decision and the gradient is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single equation but a series of equations. You need to include other factors in you analysis. For example the temperature of the motor is related to the load and thus power dissipation. Referring to basic ohms law equations:

Power = Voltage * Current

Power = Current squared * resistance

I am not a master mathematician but I can refer you to the following two articles that will demonstrate perhaps at a level much higher than you may have anticipated so here they are and I wish you much luck.

AC Motors: http://infohouse.p2ric.org/ref/40/39569.pdf

DC Motors: http://www.me.mtu.edu/~wjendres/ProductRealization1Course/DC_Motor_Calculations.pdf